# Print every n lines from a file

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I'm trying to print every `n`th line from file, but `n` is not a constant but a variable.

For instance, I want to replace `sed -n '1~5p'` with something like `sed -n '1~${i}p'`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Already answered on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-to-use-variables-in-sed-command

Comment: Your subject says `every n lines` but the text says `every nth line` which is a VERY different question. Post sample input and expected output to clarify.

Answer (score 11):

`awk` can also do it in a more elegant way:

```
awk -v n=YOUR_NUM 'NR%n==1' file
```

With `-v n=YOUR_NUM` you indicate the number. Then, `NR%n==1` evaluates to true just when the line number is on a form of `7n+1`, so it prints the line.

Note how good it is to use `awk` for this: if you want the lines on the form of `7n+k`, you just need to do: `awk -v n=7 'NR%n==k' file`.

#### Example

Let's print every 7 lines:

```
$ seq 50 | awk -v n=7 'NR%n==1'
1
8
15
22
29
36
43
50
```

Or in `sed`:

```
$ n=7
$ seq 50 | sed -n "1~$n p" # quote the expression, so that "$n" is expanded
1
8
15
22
29
36
43
50
```

Comment: Your answers print different things ?Surely the first one should be `NR%n==1` ?

Comment: @Jidder you are indeed right. Updated with more information and explanation. Thanks!

Comment: The `awk` version works also on MacOS, while the `sed` version doesn't.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that I don't always have to use `NR%n==0`. I've been doing things like `'(NR-1)%2==0'`.

Answer (score 9):

The point is, you should use double quote `"` instead of the single one to wrap your sed codes. Variable won't be expanded within single quote. so:

```
sed -n "1~${i} p"
```

Comment: This doesn't work on MacOS though. The `awk` version below works also on MacOS.

Comment: @Sampo it depends on which sed do you installed, (very likely you have bsd sed).  If you read OP's question, `1~5p` worked for him.

Comment: Sure, but this question comes up when searching for a general "every nth line" solution. It's useful to know which solutions are more widely compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this for example:

```
i=3
sed "2,${i}s/.*/changed line/g" InputFile
```

**Example:**

```
AMD$ cat File
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
fffffffffffffffffffff
ggggggggggggggggggggg

AMD$ i=4; sed "2,${i}s/.*/changed line/g" File
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
changed line
changed line
changed line
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
fffffffffffffffffffff
ggggggggggggggggggggg
```

The key is to use `" "` for variable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

why a sed ?

```
head -${i} YourFile
```

Comment: The OP states "I'm trying to print every nth line from file", this means for example the 1st, 11th, 21th, etc. Your answer is not doing this

Comment: @fedorqui: ok missunderstanding, i understand print the n first line and not all the nth line, sorry

Comment: @NeronLeVelu not your fault - the subject of the question IS to print n lines, not print nth line, and the OP didn't post any input/output to give us a clue.